# database design for storing sabre booking info

Tags: database-design, sabre

I want to build an online reservation system from Sabre. But I don't know if I should store booking data to my database. if yes, could you share any ideas how database design will look?

Answer (score 0):

The question is if you need to service the booking after everything has been traveled and a keep element is not being able to set so far in the future. If this is the case i would just query it from Sabre directly (as also the versioning is way better handled by Sabre). If you need this data long into the future i would look into schemas of https://opentravel.org/